# how to write events for formview inside header buttons? odoo 10

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

I have tried this code in odoo10 community but not working, what is my fault?

Or Can anyone guide me how to do it?

```
    openerp.module_name= function (instance) {

            var _t = instance.web._t, QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

                instance.web.FormView = instance.web.FormView.include({
                init: function() {
                        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
                        console.log("test"+this.getParent().dataset.model); 
                    },
                    events: {
                       'click #target': 'button_clicked',
                    },
                    button_clicked : function(ev) { 
                        console.log("test333555555");
                        ev.preventDefault();
                        ev.stopPropagation();
                        console.log("test 333333333333");
                    });         

                 },

            });
};
```

Comment: hi viki Chavada, did you know the solution..

Comment: So, you want button on header mean where the create and edit button in form view right?

Comment: no not that button, which is inside of form view , for example in sale order form conformsale , cancel button like that.....

Comment: Fisrt of all above code is not for odoov10. and second can you tell me exactly what do you want to perform on that button click in form view?

Comment: i have working with alfresco and odoo integration using via cmis js api, using this js api i want to create cmis session,i have button inside form like canel, confirm which is inside form. not edit,create,save, then i want to perform click event on that button..thats it

Comment: basically i need click event, which is inside of form view...

Comment: you know solution ,@VikiChavada

Comment: Yes, i will post it.

Comment: thanks for you response.............!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Create button where ever you want to create with some modifications.

```
<button string="Click" custom="click"/>
```

Then create one **JS** file that will contain following code.

```
odoo.define('YOUR_MODULE.FILENAME', function (require) {
"use strict";

var form_widget = require('web.form_widgets');
var core = require('web.core');
var _t = core._t;
var QWeb = core.qweb;

form_widget.WidgetButton.include({
    on_click: function() {
         if(this.node.attrs.custom === "click"){

            // YOUR CODE

            return;
         }
         this._super();
    },
});
});
```

**Add this JS to XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
        <template id="assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
          <xpath expr="." position="inside">
              <script type="text/javascript" src="/YOURMODULE/static/js/FILENAME.js"></script>
          </xpath>
        </template>
</odoo>
```

**Add that xml in __manifest__.py**

```
{
...
...
'data': [
        ...
        'views/above_xml_filename.xml',
    ],
....
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: drop your email-id here i will contact you.

Comment: hello KLN, I am having a problem with this pop up box. Can you help me out? @KLN

Comment: Please help me to do it in odoo11. I have tried this code in odoo 11. But I got an error "web.form_widgets" is missing dependency.