# Odoo javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9

Is it possible create my own button and this button click call javascript function? Like simple onclick javascript method?

If the answer is yes, how can I do that?

I want to use "Add an item" button or create my own button that calls the same function like I click on "Add an item" button.

Answer (score 3):

First Create button where ever you want to create with some modifications.

```
<button string="Click" custom="click"/>
```

Then create one JS file that will contain following code.

```
odoo.define('YOUR_MODULE.FILENAME', function (require) {
"use strict";

var form_widget = require('web.form_widgets');
var core = require('web.core');
var _t = core._t;
var QWeb = core.qweb;

form_widget.WidgetButton.include({
    on_click: function() {
         if(this.node.attrs.custom === "click"){

            // YOUR CODE

            return;
         }
         this._super();
    },
});
});
```

i have posed this type of question, i got this solution this answer working partially. please refer this link [how to write events for formview inside header buttons? odoo 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350936/how-to-write-events-for-formview-inside-header-buttons-odoo-10)

Comment: I was trying your example. Create button and put ir in my tree view but get an error: 

TypeError: field is undefined

http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/99692-19ff2ec/web.assets_backend.js:3463
Traceback:
init/this.$current<@http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/99692-19ff2ec/web.assets_backend.js:3463:63
dispatch@http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/98187-309e876/web.assets_common.js:740:378
add/elemData.handle@http://0.0.0.0:8069/web/content/98187-309e876/web.assets_common.js:713:151

I am using Odoo9. Can't find what is wrong.

Comment: I installed Point Of Sale. Tried to add button in Purchases -> after  Fiscal Position. And then get another error: Odoo Server Error ..... TypeError: exec_workflow() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)