# Testing a simple javascript function in odoo

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-10

I'm trying to create a simple javascript code in odoo 10. So Under myModule\static\src\js folder I added a test.js file containing this code:

```
alert("it works!!");
```

And Under myModule\views I added an xml file containing this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="solixy assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/solixyProject/static/src/js/test.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
```

And it works fine when I update my module and refresh odoo. Now I want this js code to be called when I press a button. So I changed js code like this:

```
function clickMe(){
    alert("it works!!");
};
```

Then in my form I added this button:

```
<button name="test_js" string="Test Javascript File" type="object" class="btn-primary" onclick="clickMe()"/>
```

Now the button is shown but I don't have my alert box!!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you check your browser console to ensure the JS is loaded and to see if it is throwing any errors?

Comment: Yes I got this error: `Unreachable code after return statement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I'm missing many other javascript code so my method can work. We can't just add a method like this:

```
function clickMe(){
    alert("it works!!");
};
```

This is the correct js code:

```
odoo.define('solixyProject.kanban_view', function (require){
"use strict";
var form_widget = require('web.form_widgets');
var core = require('web.core');
var _t = core._t;
var QWeb = core.qweb;

form_widget.WidgetButton.include({
    on_click: function() {
         if(this.node.attrs.custom === "click"){

            alert("It works!!");

            return;
         }
         this._super();
    },
});
});
```

And this is the correct xml code:

```
<button string="Test Javascript Onclick Method" custom="click" />
```

This question helped me a lot:
[Odoo javascript onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555023/odoo-javascript-onclick-event)

Comment: how did u solved the problem here?

TypeError: exec_workflow() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)